# Regular expression: how to capture the beginning, a pattern and the end of a line?

Tags: php, regex

Here are some examples:

1. `Some text A`
2. `Some text A 8:00-19:00`
3. `8:00-19:00`
4. `Some text A 8:00-19:00 Some text B`

For each case described above, I need to capture (if possible):

- The time (`8:00-19:00`)
- The beginning (`Some text A`)
- The end (`Some text B`)

With this pattern `#^(.*?) ?(\d{1,2}:\d{2}-\d{1,2}:\d{2})?$#`, I can capture (from example 2):

- `Some text A`
- `8:00-19:00`

But I can't capture the rest of the line by adding `(.*)` or `(.*?)` at the end of the pattern.

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: In those four examples you gave, do you need to capture them all? or just the ones which have a datetime?

Comment: This "Some text A" and "Some text B" are some values that has to be exact or it may vary?

Comment: I mean, if you have to match only when this has a specific value or if it have to match at any value before and after the times.

Comment: Tivie: Yes, I need to capture all of them, even those without time (in this case, the whole line will be captured). rcdmk: The text before and after the time may vary. I need to capture them when there is a time (or not, as a said to Tivie).

Comment: Maybe regex isn't the correct tool for the job.

Comment: @Truth its easy to handle that simple corner case outside of the regex, see my updated answer

Comment: Then check my answer. It captures all your examples, divided properly in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main problem is that you've made the group of digits optional by adding `?` after it (which I don't think you want).

This works for me `/^(.*) ?(\d{1,2}:\d{2}-\d{1,2}:\d{2}) ?(.*)$/`:

```
<?

$str = "Some text A 8:00-19:00 Some text B";
$pat = "/^(.*) ?(\d{1,2}:\d{2}-\d{1,2}:\d{2}) ?(.*)$/";

if(preg_match($pat, $str, $matches)){
   /*

    Cases 2, 3 and 4

    Array
    (
        [0] => Some text A 8:00-19:00 Some text B
        [1] => Some text A 
        [2] => 8:00-19:00
        [3] => Some text B
    )

   */
}else{
   /* Case 1 */
}

?>
```

Comment: doesn't split the matches into 1-3 groups, only gives full matching lines which is not what the OP wants

Comment: This works with the cases 2, 3 and 4. But not the first one :)

Comment: If it doesn't match grab the whole input

Comment: Woops, sorry, I totally forgot to test on the first case. As @robinr said, if there's no match then you just grab the whole string (I edited to show this). Admittedly the pure regex solution that is posted is better than this.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) ?

```
$tests = array(
    'Some text A',
    'Some text A 8:00-19:00',
    '8:00-19:00',
    'Some text A 8:00-19:00 Some text B'
);

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    $res = preg_split('/(\d\d?:\d\d-\d\d?:\d\d)/', $test, -1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    print_r($res);
}
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Some text A
)
Array
(
    [0] => Some text A 
    [1] => 8:00-19:00
)
Array
(
    [0] => 8:00-19:00
)
Array
(
    [0] => Some text A 
    [1] => 8:00-19:00
    [2] =>  Some text B
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I accepted Gordon's answer because it is more appropriate in my existing code. Yours can apply too :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $pattern = <<<REGEX
/
(?:
    (.*)?\s*                    #Prefix with trailing spaces
    (
        (?:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}-?)   #(dd:dd)-?
        {2}                     #2 of those
    )                           #(The time)
    \s*(.*)                     #Trailing spaces and suffix
    |
    ([a-zA-Z ]+)                #Either that, or just text with spaces
)
/x
REGEX;

    preg_match($pattern, "Some text A 8:00-19:00 Some text B", $matches);

    print_r($matches);
```

The array `$matches` will contain all the parts you need.

Edit: Now matches just text as well.

Comment: I know I should have probably used `\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}`, but I was lazy and wanted to cut the pattern shorter :D

Comment: does not match for `some text A` (example 1), or does it? didn't test.

Comment: Thank you Truth. As Kaii said, it matches example 2, 3 and 4, but not example 1. I tried to add a `?` quatifier, but nothing matches anymore...

Comment: of course you can easily handle that corner case as part of the regex as well ;-) +1

Comment: Well, this works for non-accented characters. I'm French, and I just tested with a c-cedilla (`ç`)... :-). I don't understand why the regex engine cannot match `Some text B` with `(.*)` to the end of the pattern. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Because that matches everything you can throw at it in any combination.

Comment: OK, so what about to make it non greedy with `(.*?)`?

Answer (score 0):

OK... I don't understand exactly what are the case scenarios.

I believe you want to match 3 optional groups (which will probably match "malformed" input, unless you provide case scenarios you DON'T want to match).

This works in all for examples, although in case 1, "Some text A" appears in $matches[0] and $matches[3] instead of $matches[1].

```
/^([A-Za-z ]*?)([0-2]{0,1}[0-9]\:[0-6][0-9]\-[0-2]{0,1}[0-9]\:[0-6][0-9])?([A-Za-z ]*?)$/
```

Comment: this works for the example input given, but not when the text before or after the time contains decimals .. (e.g. `meet 3 guys from 9:00-11:00 somewhere`)

Comment: You didn't specify that the text had numbers also... so your text can have ANY kind of characters?! All of them? like # & ´ ~ @ and so on?

Comment: No the OP didn't - i just wanted to add that as a remark / limitation of your regex.